# Sending Email Using System.Net.Mail in C#

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, system.net.mail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send email using System.Net.Mail through gmail. (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677258/send-email-using-system-net-mail-through-gmail-c)

I am using this code to send email using C# .Net
but it generates error at run-time. The Code is:

```
 MailMessage MyMailMessage = new MailMessage("example@gmail.com", "example@gmail.com",

"write your subject Here ", "Hi,This is the test message ");

MyMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = false;

NetworkCredential mailAuthentication = new NetworkCredential("example@gmail.com","xxxxxxxx");

    SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

    mailClient.EnableSsl = true;

    mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

    mailClient.Credentials = mailAuthentication;

    mailClient.Send(MyMailMessage);
```

After adding my gmail username and password and running the code an exception occurs at

```
mailClient.Send(MyMailMessage);
```

with message

```
Failure sending mail.
```

I've tried port 25 too but the problem is still there.

Is there anything else required other than Visual Studio and .Net Frameworks?
I've all the versions of .Net Frameworks.

Please Help me!

Comment: Is there an inner exception giving more info?

Comment: Your code worked for me. Are you sure your username and password are correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following,

```
  var smtp = new SmtpClient
                    {
                        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                        Port = 587,
                        EnableSsl = true,
                        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(<type your email address>, <type your password>)
                    };
                    using (var message = new MailMessage(<type your email address>, toAddress)
                    {
                        Subject = <subject>,
                        Body = <body>
                    })
                    {
                        smtp.Send(message);
                    }
```

Answer (score 4):

These are the settings that I use for sending email from GMail, place them in your web.config and then you only need to use `new SmtpClient().Send(msg);` for sending your mail. It's very convenient if you send mail from multiple places in your application. It also allows you to change your mail configuration without having to recompile your application

```
<configuration>
    <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" >
                <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="an-email@gmail.com" password="********" enableSsl="true" defaultCredentials="false" />
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT:** Since you should already have the `configuration` element in your web.config, be sure to only copy/paste the `system.net` element, I usually put it directly below `system.web`

Answer (score 1):

Gmail SSL port is 465, as seen here... http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287

Comment: well... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806944/failure-sending-mail-via-google-smtp

Comment: There is no effect of changing port... ;(

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/489594/707000

"The above answer doesn't work. You have to set "DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network" or it will come back with a "client was not authenticated" error. Also it's always a good idea to put a timeout."

Comment: It says **"The operation has timed out."**.

Comment: Are you sure you're not being blocked by a firewall or internet filter?

Answer (score 0):

a quick search shows most examples do not explicitly set `mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;` try removing this line and see if it works.

in the examples I saw they used both port 587 and 25.

Comment: I would follow the advice of the other answers to see if that resolves the error.