# Bonobo Git Server SMTP Settings

Tags: windows-7, iis-7, smtp, bonobo

I have Bonobo Git Server version 3.6 installed on my Win 7 PC. Today, I tried  on forgotten password, but it popup error message saying `Unable to send email. Validate SMTP settings.`.

How & where can I set the SMTP settings?

Comment: One thing I learned is that you can manipulate the database, so whenever you have a password problem, you download a new bonobo and then create a new user, take the password and salt of that user and set to your account you're having problem with the password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bonobo uses standard .NET smtp settings.

These can be specified in the web.config for your Bonobo-installation.

You can read the [details here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164240%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) , but basically you should add a `<mailSettings>` group under configuration\system.net

The following is a working albeit simple example. It is possible to use any smtp server and as you can read in the link, it is also possible to provide a variety of security settings.

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="network" from="bonobo@bonoserver.your.domain">
            <network 
                host="accessible.smtp.host"
                port="25"
                />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

[More details about the network element here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164242%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have tried to add <system.net> into web.config file found in Bonobo Git Server folder. But it still doesn't work. How can I put in the username & password of the account that I want to use to send email?

Comment: You can add username and password attributes to the <network /> element.   <network host="xxx.xx.xxx.229" userName="xxxxxxxx" password="xxxxxxxx"/>

Comment: I have tried, but still doesn't work with the same error message. This is my settings.
`<mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="network" from="myname@gmail.com">
            <network 
                host="smtp.gmail.com"
                port="587"
                userName="myname@gmail.com"
                password="My Password"
                defaultCredentials="true"
                enableSsl="false"
                />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>`
Any idea why still not work?

Comment: There can be a pelthora of reasons. Are you sure you are not behind a firewall? -- But you will most definately need ssl.

Comment: Yes, I am not behind a firewall. At least, I am able to get mail sending with such setting on WampServer. Tried with SSL enabled, but still the same. Google seems to be using TLS. How can I put that in?

Comment: Should be interchangeable AFAIK. The error you present is simply bonobo saying "something went wrong". Try mailing with the same settings from another program. Bonobo does a "new SmtpClient()" and uses that for sending. So test your settings elsewhere. Or try another server. Technically your question has been answered long ago, and should now be rephrased to "how do I connect a standard .NET SmtpClient to gmail."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806944/failure-sending-mail-via-google-smtp/7807010#7807010 try settings from accepted answer.

Comment: Really thanks a lot for your help here. I have tried with those new settings, but still fail to send the mail.