# Bonobo Unable to send email. Validate SMTP settings

Tags: c#, git, iis, bonobo

I have installed bonobo version 6.3.0 and I'm having hard time to recover passwords, it is giving me this error "Unable to send email. Validate SMTP settings".

I already set up my mailSettings in webconfig

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="user name" password="password" enableSsl="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
 </system.net>
```

This still doesn't work, I thought the problem was with my remote machine where my bonobo server is, then I created one here on my local machine and I'm getting the same error.

Does somebody have any idea?

Comment: Did you read through [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260)? There's some steps you have to take to modify your Gmail settings. Look particularly at the answer from BCS Software.

Comment: The thing is I already use this same configuration in other projects and it  works.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Bonobo. Are you sure it reads the mailSettings from the config file? Perhaps it's not.

Comment: I saw a thread here on stackoverflow,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737754/bonobo-git-server-smtp-settings/feed/

The guy said it does

Answer (score 1):

I know you are asking for gmail, but to help people with default hosting service, I added details here.

Go to your Bonobo Git installation, open `Web.config`.
Here is my working configuration:

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>  
    <mailSettings>  
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="noreply@yourdomain.com">  
        <network  
          defaultCredentials="false"  
          enableSsl="false"  
          host="server.hosting.ch"
          password="secretpassword#123"  
          port="587"
          userName="noreply@yourdomain.com" 
        />  
      </smtp>  
    </mailSettings>  
  </system.net>   
</configuration>
```

This is based on documentation of web.config of Microsoft: [Network settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/network-element-network-settings?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Now to use Gmail, you can unlock for your client system described here: [Gmail setup SMTP and POP3 for Mailclient](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828?hl=en)